# How to get rating value (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$rating = $rowsRaing;


Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ratting] => 2.5
        )

)
```

> I want rating value.

I want user average number of ratting help me 
**Thanks**

Comment: I suggest to do some research yourself, you should find the solution quite easy. Please show us some of your effort, what you have done, what you receive and what you want to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be

```
$rowsRaing = $wpdb->get_results("select avg(ratting) as rating from tablename where id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'");

$rat=$rowsRaing;
$RatingVal = $rat[0]->rating;
```

By using this variable you get the avg number of ratting 
**"$RatingVal"**

Comment: You have introduced a SQL injection error here; **never** interpolate REQUEST data into a SQL query, you have given an attacker full access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It's var of object inside array, so:

```
$yourRatingValue = $rat[0]->rating;
```